# React: Use props or array of these

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Could you tell me please. How can I make React component which I can use with props or with array of these props.

For example I have this component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Links extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <a
                href={ this.props.link }
            >
                { this.props.name }
            </a>
        )
    }
}
```

And I want to use this component here:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Links from './Links'

export default class Block extends Component {
    render () {
        const social = [{
            name: 'Twitter',
            link: 'https://twitter.com',
        }, {
            name: 'FaceBook',
            link: 'https://fb.com',
        }]
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Links someword={ social }>
                </div>
                <Links name={ 'Google' } link={ 'https://google.com' }>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not have a `<Link name={...} link={...}/>` component and renders one link and and a `<Links data={social}>` that renders multiple `<Link>`s?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your social array and map each value to your `Links` component and  then put it in the `render` function of your `Block` component.

```js
export default class Block extends Component {
    render () {
        const social = [{
            name: 'Twitter',
            link: 'https://twitter.com',
        }, {
            name: 'FaceBook',
            link: 'https://fb.com',
        }]
        
        const linkComps = social.map(e =>
          <Links name={ e.name } link={e.link} key={e.name} />;
        );
        
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                  { linkComps }
                </div>
                <Links name={ 'Google' } link={ 'https://google.com' }>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to include a key for each link

Comment: You can simplify this a little by using `map` instead of `forEach`.  `const linkComps = social.map(e => <Links name={ e.name } link={e.link} /> `

Comment: inside map you need to return something, push is not required.

Comment: I'm assuming that he wants to render the links based on the `social` variable.

Comment: There's no need to assume. OP described what he wants: "How can I make [a] React component which I can use with props or with [an] array of these props."

Comment: Looks like it's not good idea. I can have more than one array

Comment: What do you mean by that @EntryGuy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to iterate the `array` and create the `Links` component. Since your `social` variable is having the const value, so instead of defining that inside `render` method, define it outside in the starting of the file.

Write it like this:

```js
 const social = [{
            name: 'Twitter',
            link: 'https://twitter.com',
        }, {
            name: 'FaceBook',
            link: 'https://fb.com',
        }
]

class Block extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    {
                      social.map((el,i) => <Links 
                                              key={i} 
                                              name={el.name} 
                                              link={el.link} />)
                    }
                </div>
                <Links name={ 'Google' } link={ 'https://google.com' }/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Links extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <a
                href={ this.props.link }
            >
                { this.props.name }
            </a>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Block/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

If you want to handle that inside Links component, you can write it like this, You can pass either an `array` by name `array` or pass the individual value by `name and Link`.

```
export default class Links extends Component {

    _renderLinks(){
        if(this.props.array && Array.isArray(this.props.array)){
            return this.props.array.map((el,i) => <a 
                                                     key={i} 
                                                     href={ el.link}
                                                  >  
                                                     {el.name} 
                                                  </a>
        }else{
            return <a href={ this.props.link}> {this.props.name} </a>
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                {this._renderLinks()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to render multiple components from an array of props is with `map`:

```
render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div>
      {social.map(props => (
        <Link key={props.link} {...props}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

That said, having a single component that takes two different kinds of props is, generally speaking, a bad idea. That is to say, a component should take e.g. `name` and `link` props *or* it should take an array of objects with those properties. It should not do both.

A clean way to solve your problem is to have two components: A `<Link>` component that takes `name` and `link` props and renders a single link, and a `<Links>` (plural) component that takes an array of objects with those properties and renders a `<Link>` (singular) component for each one.

A basic implementation looks like the below. Click on <kbd>▸⃝ Run code snippet</kbd> below to see it in action (note that I added some CSS just to show the boundaries of each component).

```js
const Link = ({name, link}) => (
  <a href={link}>{name}</a>
);

const Links = ({links}) => (
  <div>
    {links.map(props => <Link key={props.link} {...props}/>)}
  </div>
);

class Block extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Render an array of links with <Links> */}
        <Links links={this.props.social}/>

        {/* Render a single link with <Link> */}
        <Link name="Google" link="https://google.com"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const social = [
  { name: 'Twitter',
    link: 'https://twitter.com',
  },
  { name: 'Facebook',
    link: 'https://facebook.com',
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(<Block social={social}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```css
a {display: block;}
div div {border: 1px dotted gray; padding: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```